# Converting .Net object to JSON missing most properties

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm playing around with Web API 4 for the first time and preparing to hook up connection to a MongoDb. I've defined some simple objects to represent the models but when I try to return a collection of them from the GET request of my API only one property is being included in the resulting JSON object.

```
public class Topic : Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Topic> Parents { get; set; }
    public List<Topic> Children { get; set; }
    public List<ContentNode> ContentNodes { get; set; }
}

public class ContentNode
{
    public enum ContentNodeType { VIDEO, TEXT, AUDIO };
    public ContentNodeType ContentType { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public List<int> Scores { get; set; }
    public List<Link> Links { get; set; }
    public List<string> Comments { get; set; }
}

public string Get()
    {
        List<Topic> topics = new List<Topic>();
        var programming = new Topic()
        {
            Id = "1",
            Name = "Programming"
        };

        var inheritanceVideo = new ContentNode() 
        {
            ContentType = ContentNode.ContentNodeType.VIDEO,
            Url = "http://youtube.com",
            Scores = new List<int>() {
                4, 4, 5
            },
            Comments = new List<string>() {
                "Great video about inheritance!"
            }
        };

        var oop = new Topic()
        {
            Id = "2",
            Name = "Object Oriented Programming",
            ContentNodes = new List<ContentNode>() {
                inheritanceVideo
            }
        };

        programming.Children.Add(oop);
        topics.Add(programming);
        string test = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(topics);
        return test;
    }
```

I'm using the JSON.Net library to serialize the object here but I previously used the default JSON serializer and had the GET return `IEnumerable<Topic>`. In both cases the JSON being returned is simply:

```
"[{\"Id\":\"1\"}]"
```

A browser request for the XML works just fine. According to the documentation for JSON.Net it doesn't seem like there should be a problem serializing these classes to JSON. Any thoughts on why this isn't working? It doesn't seem like I should need to apply explicit attributes for every member.

Comment: These classes should serialize fine, and I've tested and it works for me. What is the `Entity` class that Topic inherits from?

Comment: I didn't see Ergwun's comment and tested this myself.  I was also unable to reproduce.  Obviously I didn't have access to the Entity and Link objects, so I removed them from the code.  If there is a problem, it's likely with the Entity object.